# Flipping heads 10 times in a row

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If I flip a coin 10 times in a row, obviously the probability of rolling heads ten times in a row is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10}$. However, I am not sure how to calculate the exact odds that I will have *at some point* rolled heads 10 times in a row during a series of n flips. I have written a program to calculate the odds, but it runs in exponential time on n so it is relatively unusable. Here are the first couple results:

```
in 10 rolls, 0.0009765625.
in 11 rolls, 0.00146484375.
in 12 rolls, 0.001953125.
in 13 rolls, 0.00244140625.
in 14 rolls, 0.0029296875.
in 15 rolls, 0.00341796875.
in 16 rolls, 0.00390625.
in 17 rolls, 0.00439453125.
in 18 rolls, 0.0048828125.
in 19 rolls, 0.00537109375.
in 20 rolls, 0.005859375.
in 21 rolls, 0.006347179412841797.
in 22 rolls, 0.006834745407104492.
in 23 rolls, 0.007322072982788086.
in 24 rolls, 0.007809162139892578.
in 25 rolls, 0.008296012878417969.
in 26 rolls, 0.008782625198364258.
in 27 rolls, 0.009268999099731445.
in 28 rolls, 0.009755134582519531.
in 29 rolls, 0.010241031646728516.
in 30 rolls, 0.010726690292358398.
```

The source code is [here](https://gist.github.com/unixpickle/6503662)

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability  ?

Comment: @AlexNichol: You might like to read: http://gato-docs.its.txstate.edu/mathworks/DistributionOfLongestRun.pdf

Comment: I do not know CS, but for the case $n=12$ I get a different result. Counting the number of strings with $10$ heads in a row we have: $(H...H)**$ by $*$ I mean anything could go there, so $4$. Or $T(H...H)*$, which gives me $2$, and $TT(H...H)$ which gives me $1$, so $7/2^{12}$, but that is not what your code gives.

Comment: There is also TH(H…H) and HT(H…H)

Comment: I guess HT(H…H) is the only one you don't list there, but either way i'm relatively confident my code gives the correct answer since it enumerates all possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the next 20 numbers on the list (hint hint...non-exponential time algorithm):

```
in 31 rolls, 0.0112121105194
in 32 rolls, 0.0116972925607
in 33 rolls, 0.0121822365327
in 34 rolls, 0.0126669425517
in 35 rolls, 0.0131514107343
in 36 rolls, 0.0136356411967
in 37 rolls, 0.0141196340555
in 38 rolls, 0.0146033894271
in 39 rolls, 0.0150869074278
in 40 rolls, 0.015570188174
in 41 rolls, 0.0160532317823
in 42 rolls, 0.0165360383689
in 43 rolls, 0.0170186080503
in 44 rolls, 0.0175009409426
in 45 rolls, 0.0179830371621
in 46 rolls, 0.0184648968248
in 47 rolls, 0.0189465200469
in 48 rolls, 0.0194279069443
in 49 rolls, 0.0199090576331
in 50 rolls, 0.0203899722291
```

Here's the Python code (the above is the output of a call to **makelist(10,31,50)**):

```
import numpy

def transitionmatrix(n):
    N = 2**n
    A = numpy.matrix([[0.0]*N]*N)
    A[0,0] = 1
    for i in range(1,N):
        A[(2*i)% N,i] = 0.5
        A[(2*i+1)%N,i] = 0.5
    return A

def makelist(n,a,b):
    A = transitionmatrix(n)
    N = 2**n
    v = numpy.matrix([1./N]*N).T
    B = A**(a-n)
    for i in range(a,b+1):
        p = (B*v)[0,0]
        print('in '+str(i)+' rolls, '+str(p))
        B = A*B
```

Comment: Yes, before checking these answers I successfully came up with a Markov chain similar to this one that can ultimately give a closed form solution. I appreciate your use of actual code.

Comment: Alex, could you provide your closed form solution? I have recently asked this question myself and your question here was most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt: So denote by $P_i$ the probability of having $10$ heads in a row in $i$ tosses. So $P_{10}=1/2^{10}$.

For $i=10,...,20$, we can calculate the probability straight forward by saying: Probability that I get $10$ heads row and my heads start at $1$ plus probability that I get $10$ heads in a row and I start at $2$ plus, and so on. For instance, for $i=16$ we have $1/2^{10}+6/2^{11}=0.390625$ precisely what you got.

When $i>20$, then the counting becomes a little more messy, but I think its doable using recursion. Note that $P_{i+1}=P_i+$Probability that my $10$ heads in a row start at $i-9$ (let me denote this probability $Q_i$). So you know that $P_i$ is for the first couple of cases, note that $Q_i$ for $i\leq 20$ is just $1/2^{11}$ because we need a $T$ to go on the $i-10$ position and followed by $10$ heads, however, that does not work for say $i=21$ because we want more, we want the $11$th position to be a $T$, the following to be 10 $H$s, and the previouse ones not to be a string of $10$ heads because we are counting the strings whose starting point is at $12$. Thus, $Q_{21}=(1/2^{11})(1-P_{10})$. Hence, $P_{21}=P_{20}+Q_{21}$ to exactly what you have.

For $P_{22}=P_{21}+Q_{22}$ where $Q_{22}=(1/2^{11})(1-P_{11})$, I just checked and indeed I get the same result.

In general, you can build them recursively, and use $Q_i=(1/2^{11})(1-P_{i-11})$.

A little more clear (above was me thinking as I typed, so it turned out somewhat messy): You can denote $P_0,..,P_9$ all to be $0$, $P_{10}=1/2^{10}$, and $P_n=P_{n-1}+(1/2^{11})(1-P_{n-11})$.

Comment: I just checked and my recursion agrees with all your values. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent (2002) book by Balakrishnan and Koutras, title bein "Runs and Scans etc ...", that studies in detail the probability distribution of the number of such runs after $n$ flips or even the probability distribution of the number of flips needed to observe $n$ such runs.

ISBN 0-471-24892-4

There, you will find closed form expression and asymptotics, as well as some bibliography.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is the probability of a run. This appears to be a problem going back to [De Moirve](http://ranmath.webng.com/problems/run.htm). Wolfram has a detailed exposition [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Run.html) which includes generating functions and recurrence relations. Unfortunately, closed form calculations seem to be difficult to come by.

Answer (score 0):

There are constants $c,\alpha$ such that, for $n \ge 11$,  $$P_n = 1-c\alpha^n$$ with the error less than $2^{-n}$ :  $$\alpha\approx 0.999509316355050569331704619564576430927155038 \hskip{0.5in}c\approx 1.0039472560945626.$$

---

It is easier to look first at the probability $Q_k=1-P_k$ of **not** having any run of $10$ consecutive heads in $k$ flips of a (fair) coin. So $Q_0=Q_1=\cdots Q_9=1$ , $Q_{10}=1-1/2^{10}$ and then for $n \ge 11$ we have $$Q_{n}=Q_{n-1}-\frac{Q_{n-11}}{2^{11}}$$

A standard approach to this homogeneous recurrence relation is to look at the roots of $$X^{11}-X^{10}+\frac{1}{2^{11}}=(X-\frac12)(X^{10}-\frac{X^9}{2}-\frac{X^8}{4}-\cdots-\frac{X}{2^9}-\frac{1}{2^{10}})$$

These turn out to be three real roots $-0.49515547\cdots,0.5,\alpha=0.999509316355\cdots$ along with eight complex roots all with modulus between $0.451$ and $0.484$

From this one knows that $$\frac{Q_{k+1}}{Q_k}\approx \alpha.$$ This is true to high accuracy (starting at $k=10$ with the accuracy improving rapidly). And from this we know that there is an asymptotic formula as at the start.

---

The recurrence I used is from putting $P_k=1-Q_k$ in the one given by Daniel. An alternate recurrence (basically factoring out the $(X-\frac12)$ ) is:

$Q_0=Q_1=\cdots Q_9=1$ $Q_{10}=1-1/2^{10}$ and then for $N \ge 10$:

$$Q_{N}=\sum_{j=1}^{10}\frac{Q_{N-j}}{2^{j}}$$ Because $\frac{Q_{N-j}}{2^{j}}$ is the probability of first $j-1$ flips being heads, then flip $j$ being a tail, then $N-j$ more flips without a run of 10 heads. The analysis is then the same.