# If a coin is flipped 1024 times, what is the likelihood that heads is flipped 10 times in a row exactly twice?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Suppose I flip a coin $1,024$ times in a row. I understand that to find the probability of flipping heads $10$ times in a row **at least** once, I could find the probability of being able to flip heads ten times in a row using $1-(\frac{1023}{1024})^{1024}$ since $(\frac{1023}{1024})^{1024}$ is the probability of not flipping heads $10$ times in a row during the $1,024$ trials. However, I do not understand how to calculate the probability of heads being flipped exactly $10$ times (each occurrence must be separated by flipping tails) in a row in $1,024$ trials **exactly** $n$ times, where $n=2$ in this case.

Thanks in advance for any input

Comment: How do you treat overlaps?   That is, is $H^{11}T^{1013}$ a success or a fail?  Beyond that, I expect recursion is your best bet (though you'll still need to automate it).

Comment: Start by computing the probability of getting no such streaks in $n$ trials.  That's a routine recursion.  Then do the probability of getting exactly one.  And so on.

Comment: A case like $H^{11}T^{1013}$ would be a failure, since it's not exactly ten heads in a row. I was hoping I could do it without having to automate it, but if there's no other way, then I guess I may try that.

Comment: YOur assertion "since $(1023/1024)^{1024}$  is the probability of not flipping heads 10 times in a row during the 1,024 trials" makes no sense to me.  Actually the answer is not trivial. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489055/flipping-heads-10-times-in-a-row?rq=1

Comment: I don't understand. Your header question asks for the probability of throwing $H^{10}$ exactly twice.  Well, throwing $H^{11}$ does that.  Please explain.

Comment: Whatever the rules are, recursive methods are indicated.  Just be sure you understand your rules before you try to automate them.  The code won't sort the rules out for you.

Comment: @lulu I hope the OP will correct me if I'm wrong, but I think they're expecting two sequences of exactly 10 heads in a row (separated by at least one tails). So, $H^{11}T^{1013}$ would have zero instances of 10 heads in a row, not two.

Comment: @TheoBendit  I mean...maybe?  But why guess?  If the OP is going to program this, they will have to understand their own rules and be able to state them clearly, without room for doubt.  Computers don't handle ambiguity well.

Comment: leonbloy, I came up with $(1023/1024)^{1024}$ using the Binomial Distribution Formula, where $(1024C0)*((1/1024)^0)*(1023/1024)^{1024}=1*(1023/1024)^{1024}$. Was I wrong with thinking that? Also, Theo Bendit is correct with his assumption, I apologize as I should have made that clear in the original question.

Comment: So  $H^{10}TH^{11}TH^{10}T^{991}$ is exactly two cases of $10$ heads in a row?  It is unlikely that the answer is as simple as $(1023/1024)^{1024}$